# Spring FeignClient not working with DMZ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, jhipster, netflix-feign, dmz

I have problem after deploying spring boot application in microservices architecture (jhipster).
Architecture presentation:

> - Secured zone (unavailable for users from web browser): AdminApp, ServerApp
> - DMZ (available for users): UserApp

AdminApp and UserApp have websocket implementation (spring-boot-starter-websocket). ServerApp sends event to AdminApp/UserApp. Using FeignClient ServerApp call the SocketController from AdminApp/UserApp that sends WebSocket event to frontend.

On localhost works fine. When application is deployed on two different servers without DMZ works fine too. The problem occurs with DMZ. When ServerApp send event to AdminApp (the same server) its work, but if ServerApp send event to UserApp (another server with DMZ) then i have error: Connection refused executing POST http://UserApp/api/websocket

Comment: Your architecture is not very detailed, are you using Zuul proxy somewhere on this path? Because as far as I remember Zuul does not support web sockets.

Comment: Yes, i use Zuul proxy and web socket work but without DMZ

Comment: I'm surprised about Zuul and ws: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/163

Comment: I use this implementation: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ and its work for me (without DMZ)